How can I automate IMAP Office 365 Access
Hoping you can assist as I seem to be struggling to understand the authentication options when it comes to oAuth2 and Office 365.
The system I am wanting to create is an automated process that once per hour (as an example) checks my Office 365 mailbox for new mail in a particular folder.  This sounds easy as I can use MailKit for the mailbox manipulation however I am struggling to work out the authentication process/options.
I seem to have 2 options when it comes to Microsoft.Identity.Client:

PublicClientApplicationBuilder
ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder

I understand the PublicClientApplicationBuilder as far as getting the user to authenticate via a browser and it returning a token which I assume I can then store to re-use each time.  However the token seems to expire very quickly so not sure this will work.
Here is my test code for the PublicClientApplicationBuilder:
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
    .Build();

var accounts = app.GetAccountsAsync().Result;

var scopes = new[]
{
    "User.Read",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
};

var token = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

From what I have read I really need to use the ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder but I don't know how I can get a user specific token returned.
Has anyone managed to this or should I just be using the PublicClient token?
Thanks in advance

Do you want to increase token lifetime?

@Rukmini I'm not 100% sure.  What I basically need is to have a .Net client periodically process emails within the inbox without user interaction.  If this means they authenticate once and we store a token for re-use then that works.  If we can do this another way then that works too.

You can try with acquiretokensilent. When this method is called, the library first checks the cache in browser storage to see if a non-expired access token exists and returns it. If no access token is found or the access token found has expired, it attempts to use its refresh token to get a fresh access token

Please check the below answer

Based on your requirement ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder suits your requirement.
If you want to get user specific access token with user interaction involved, then you have to make use of   PublicClientApplicationBuilder flow.

However the token seems to expire very quickly so not sure this will work.


As per your ask, you can increase the token lifetime. Refer this MsDoc

Otherwise, you can use acquiretokensilent, it first checks the cache in browser storage to see if a non-expired access token exists and returns it. If no access token is found or the access token found has expired, it attempts to use its refresh token to get a fresh access token.

AcquireTokenSilent method to reuse tokens without prompting the user every time.
-Acquires an access token for the account from the user token cache.

using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    private const string clientId = "ClientID";
    private const string tenantId = "TenantID";
    private const string redirectUri = "http://localhost"; 
    private static readonly string[] scopes = {
        "User.Read",
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
    };

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .Build();

        AuthenticationResult result;
        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

        try
        {
            // Try to acquire token silently
            result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                              .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            // Fallback to interactive login
            result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                              .ExecuteAsync();
        }

        var token = result.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + token);
    }
}


Reference:
Acquire a token to call a web API (single-page apps) - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft
